# How to find length of literal array?

Tags: javascript

So, why does this result in 0 and how do I find the actual size?

```
var array = [];
array["foo"] = "bar";
array["bar"] = "foo";

document.write(array.length);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since that is a object, which is comprised of properties, and take the form of key/value pairs (conceptually similar to an associative array, or a hash table) you will have to do something like this:

```
Object.size = function(obj) {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
};

var array = [];
array["foo"] = "bar";
array["bar"] = "foo";

var size = Object.size(array);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gBG34/

Comment: Or also: Object.prototype.size = function()...

And then you can use it like: var size = array.size()

Comment: ...or as a plain-old function, and just do `getSize(var);`

Comment: There's no such thing as an associative array in JS. It's an object and just an alternative syntax to access it's properties. Instead of `array["foo"]` you may as well write `array.foo`. That's why the length property doesn't work. He's setting properties on an array object and not adding items to an array.

Comment: @DanMan Fair enough, but how do I find how many properties the array has then?

Comment: @DanMan - But you can think of it as one. In the same way you can call it a 'hash table'. I'm aware that 'properties' can be accessed using both square bracket and dot notation.

Comment: @karim79 - Fine, but since array methods don't work on those properties i think it's wrong to call it an array. @Meke: see the other people's answers.

Comment: @José Leal: I'd strongly recommend against extending `Object.prototype` since it affects *every* type of object, and will make `hasOwnPropety` an absolute requirement, completely removing the ability to iterate over other desired `prototype` properties (unless you explicitly test to avoid the `"size"` prototyped property). @karim79's method is much safer.

Comment: This is all well and good until you add items to the Array, not properties. Each item in the array counts, too. I guess you'd need to do `size = size - (!!obj.length ? obj.length : 0)`

Comment: @hunter - Good point. I just assumed that he would want to count Array.push'ed elements too. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 7):

First off, the length is 0 because the number of items in `array` is 0.

When you do this syntax `array["foo"] = "bar"` you're creating a property called `foo` that has a value of `bar`. The length is still 0 since you have not added anything to the Array, you've just set new properties on the Array

Working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/VyjJD/3/

```
var array = [];

array["foo"] = "bar";
array["bar"] = "foo";
array.bin = function() { return "bin"; };

array[0] = "bar";
array[1] = "foo";
array[2] = "bin";
array[3] = "bat";

var props = 0;

for (key in array)
    props++;

document.write(array.length + "<br />" 
           + props + "<br />" 
           + (array.foo == array["foo"]) + "<br />" 
           + array.bar + "<br />"
           + array.bin());
```

Notice that `array.length = 4` but `props = 7` which is all of the properties and the number of items in the Array.

Answer (score 4):

You are setting a property on the array, not giving it a new element.  Arrays can receive arbitrary properties, just like any other Javascript object.  For instance:

```
var foo = [];
foo.bar = 'foobar';
console.log(foo.bar); // outputs 'foobar'
console.log(foo); // outputs [] -- empty array
```

To add items to an array, use [`Array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
var foo = [];
foo.push('foobar');
console.log(foo); // outputs ['foobar']
```

If you want key=>value pairs, use an object instead:

```
var foo = {};
foo['bar'] = 'foobar';
console.log(foo); // outputs {bar: 'foobar'}
```

Answer (score 1):

basically when you do

`array["foo"] = "bar"`

it just adds some more attributes to the array, which is an object. In javascript, array.foo and array['foo'] means the same.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out. But it doesn't answer the question?

Comment: It doesn't convert it into an object. Arrays *are* objects, so you can set arbitrary properties on them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm being naive (my javascript isn't what it might be), but shouldn't it be something like this:

```
var array = [];
array[0] = "bar";
array[1] = "foo";
document.write(array.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual size is 0 because you did not put any items into array object - this can only be done either by a method (push etc.) or by the means of assigning value to an indexed property (or in constructor).

Answer (score 0):

Object.keys(array).length

see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13802999/1488217

credits goes to ian